# Camera Preview stuck when app resume in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using a Camera plugin in the app. There are a couple of things which are not working.

1. If the app goes to sleep or in the background then it is not resuming. Camera Preview stuck. I have used AppState in the below code but that is not helping in this case. Maybe I have implemented it wrong.
2. I am trying to swap the camera and written the code below too. But that is also not working.

Here is the complete code.

```
class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  CameraPage({Key key, this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  final PageController controller;
  final double iconHeight = 30;
  final PageController bottomPageController =
      PageController(viewportFraction: .2);

  @override
  CameraPageState createState() => CameraPageState();
}

class CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _controllerInizializer;
  double cameraHorizontalPosition = 0;
  var cameras;

  Future<CameraDescription> getCamera() async {
     cameras = await availableCameras();
    return cameras[0];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getCamera().then((camera) {
        if (camera == null) return;
        setState(() {
          _controller = CameraController(
              camera,
            ResolutionPreset.medium,
            enableAudio: true
          );
          _controllerInizializer = _controller.initialize();
          _controllerInizializer.whenComplete(() {
              setState(() {
                cameraHorizontalPosition = -(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*_controller.value.aspectRatio)/2;
              });
          });
        });
    });

  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
      _controller?.dispose();
      super.dispose();
  }

  @override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _controller != null
        ? _controllerInizializer = _controller.initialize()
        : null; //on pause camera is disposed, so we need to call again 
  }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned.fill(
            left: cameraHorizontalPosition +100,
            right: cameraHorizontalPosition +100,

          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _controllerInizializer,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return CameraPreview(_controller);
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
              actions: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    widget.controller.animateToPage(
                      1,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      curve: Curves.ease,
                    );
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Container(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 50,
                    right: 40,
                    left: 40,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: widget.iconHeight,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(5),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            child: Image.network(
                              Utils.image(),
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(5),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: widget.iconHeight,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.flash_on,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(25),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          height: 70,
                          width: 70,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(35),
                            ),
                            border: Border.all(
                              width: 10,
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.5),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 70,
                          width:  70,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.cached,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 40),
                            onPressed: (){cameraswap();},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void cameraswap(){
    print('hi');

    _controller.value.isRecordingVideo
              ? null
              : onNewCameraSelected;
  } 

void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message, Color color) { //String labeltext, 
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      backgroundColor: color,
      content: Text(message),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }


  void onNewCameraSelected(CameraDescription camera) async {
if (_controller != null) {
  await _controller.dispose();
}
_controller = CameraController(
  camera,
  ResolutionPreset.high,
  enableAudio: true,
);

// If the controller is updated then update the UI.
_controller.addListener(() {
  if (mounted) setState(() {});
  if (_controller.value.hasError) {
    _showSnackBar(context,'Camera error ${_controller.value.errorDescription}', Colors.redAccent);
  }
});

try {
  await _controller.initialize();
} on CameraException catch (e) {
 print(e);
}

if (mounted) {
  setState(() {});
}
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.